# How can I add a PPA repository using Ansible?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ansible

I'm trying to add a new repository to a server so that I can install Java by Ansible. Unfortunately whenever I try to run the playbook it fails because of a GPG error. Can somebody explain what is going wrong here and what I need to do in order to fix this?

I'm using Ansible 1.7.2 and currently only connecting to localhost.

I have a very simple Playbook that looks like this:

```
- hosts: home
  tasks:
   - name: Add repositories
     apt_repository: repo='ppa:webupd8team/java' state=present
```

When I try to execute it, I get the following error:

```
sal@bobnit:~/Workspace$ ansible-playbook --ask-sudo-pass basic.yml 
sudo password: 

PLAY [home] ******************************************************************* 

GATHERING FACTS *************************************************************** 
ok: [localhost]

TASK: [Add repositories] ****************************************************** 
failed: [localhost] => {"cmd": "apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 7B2C3B0889BF5709A105D03AC2518248EEA14886", "failed": true, "rc": 2}
stderr: gpg: requesting key EEA14886 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: no writable keyring found: eof
gpg: error reading `[stream]': general error
gpg: Total number processed: 0

stdout: Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --homedir /tmp/tmp.HKDOSZnVQP --no-auto-check-trustdb --trust-model always --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/steam.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ubuntu-x-swat_ubuntu_x-updates.gpg --recv-keys --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 7B2C3B0889BF5709A105D03AC2518248EEA14886

msg: gpg: requesting key EEA14886 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: no writable keyring found: eof
gpg: error reading `[stream]': general error
gpg: Total number processed: 0

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************** 
           to retry, use: --limit @/home/sal/basic.retry

localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

Comment: You found your answer, so some tips: `apt_repository` is great, it's a good idea to use `apt_key` too. If you are installing from that repo right after, use `update_cache=yes` in the `apt_repository` arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, this seems to have been entirely caused by me forgetting the `-s` option!

Without this it wasn't using `sudo`.

Comment: where did you added the '-s' option?

Comment: In my playbook I use `sudo: yes` in the task itself.

Comment: Just a note for future Ansible versions - if `sudo: yes` doesn't work for you, try the `become : yes`

Answer (score 9):

Use a option `validate_certs` with `no`

```
  - name: Adicionando PPA do php 7.1
    apt_repository:
      validate_certs: no
      repo: 'ppa:ondrej/php'
      state: present
```